# Which of the following sentences is/are incorrect? ("Permit" vs. "allow" vs. "let")

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, infinitives, bare-infinitive

Which of the following sentences is/are incorrect? Why?

- The visa permits you to study for two months.
- My father would never allow me to study English
- Let me to go. You're hurting me.

This is question from an English learning book. All the sentences seem right to me. Do you know which one is incorrect and why?

Comment: "Let me to go" is wrong, it should be "Let me go". Unless that was a typo?

Comment: I'm going to call this "proofreading"

Comment: I am not sure if the length of the text is enough to call this proofreading, but the question throws in three different questions, and ask if they are correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The incorrect sentence is:

> Let me **to** go.  You're hurting me.

It should be:

> Let me go.

Let takes a bare infinitive (i.e. no "to").  The [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/let) has more details and examples.