# British and other English variants of 'write to me' - 'write me''

Tags: american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english, australian-english, north-american-english

In British English, the standard is 'write to me'. In American English the standard is 'write me'.
Similar variants exist with 'out of the window' and 'out the window'.
When did the dropping of prepositions start happening? 
Are there any historical or regional influences? If so, do you know of any research that has been done on these?
Finally, which version do other forms of English (eg Australian) use?

Comment: *Prepositional* *defenestration* will continue until morale improves.

Comment: @elliott frisch - guess we'll just have to order in more ale (in) the time being

Comment: Note that _write me a letter_ and _tell me_ are grammatical in (AFAIK) all varieties of English.

Comment: @ColinFine - OK, but you've added 'a letter' which wasn't in my question. By the same token you can say 'tell me' or 'tell it to me'. In Russian you'd say 'say me' (skaji mne) - you wouldn't in English (unless you meant "say 'me'") - you could say 'say it to me' or 'say it again' - but there is no dropping of the preposition in these forms (AFAIK).

Comment: Actually 'mne' is in the dative anyway - so scrub that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with "I'll open you the door"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door). Or more precisely, [Give it me! Write me!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137038/give-it-me-write-me) which was closed as a duplicate thereof.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - +1 for the links, thanks. However, I'm interested in the history/time frame aspect, which wasn't previously covered as far as I could tell.

Comment: @LeonConrad: yes, you're right that _write me a letter_ is a different construction. But the point about _tell me_ is that, as you point out, _tell_ has a different subcategorisation frame from _say_; and your question is about the fact that for some speakers, _write_ has the same frame as _tell_.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the regional dialects in Britain treat prepositions differently. In Yorkshire and Lancashire they will, for example, say 'Give it me' rather than 'give it to me', or 'give it me back'.

In the North East, the Newcastle-upon-Tyne/Sunderland area, the so-called Geordies will say 'I'm asking you for to tell me', thus inserting a 'for' into a sentence where standard English wouldn't.

There are quite a lot of others but I can't think of them late at night.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that this came about during the early 20th century when there was an influx of German and Russian immigrants into the US.  Where German and Russian would have used the dative case on 'me' and thus needed no 'to', English has no similar declensions and so 'Write to me' became contracted to 'Write me'.  The form then stuck in American English.

The catch with this story is that I have never seen any authoratative justification for it.  Therefore, I can't say if there is any truth in it.  It does however sound plausible.

I have never heard the 'Write me' form used in Australia, New Zealand, South Africa or India, although others may have better knowledge.  I have heard it used in the Caribbean.  Perhaps, due to the proximity to the US there is a greater influence.