# Do indirect objects in English always mean "to" or "for"?

Tags: indirect-objects

"I gave him two dollars."

This tacitly means "to him".  Are there exceptions to the rule that an indirect object in English always means "to" or "for"?

In English, "I stole him two dollars" does not mean "I stole two dollars from him", and one does not say "I withheld him that information" (either of those usages would be valid in German).

Comment: "I stole him two dollars" would mean "_for_ him", I guess.

Comment: Indirect objects in English are much more restrictive than in many other languages that have them, being licensed essentially by the individual verb and/or idiom directly. In ‘look someone in the eye’ or ‘stand someone a drink’, for example, it does not correspond to _any_ prepositional phrase—it can only be used as an indirect object. You cannot ‘look in the eye for/to someone’ or ‘stand a drink to/for someone’. I can’t currently think of any contexts where an indirect object could be transposed to a prepositional phrase with a preposition that isn’t either _to_ or _for_, though.

Comment: @Peter They’re indirect. For your test, try deleting whatever comes after the “somebody” argument.  If the sentence holds together, it’s direct, but if not, it’s indirect. With “I hit him on the chin” > “I hit him”, the key sense remains unchanged.  With “look somebody in the eye” > “look *somebody” just as with “look somebody over” > “look *somebody”, it no longer makes sense without a preposition inserted between the two words. Therefore the body involved could never have served as the direct object.

Comment: I had thought that in English (unlike German), a verb never has an indirect object unless it also has a direct object.  This example of "look someone in the eye" seems to be a counterexample.  I wouldn't have noticed it was an indirect object without thinking about "look someone" without the phrase that follows it.

Comment: Um... what? `look over` and `look in the eye` are idiomatic (or phrasal) verbs, they mean something different from `look` by itself (among other things, they are transitive and take direct objects, while look is not), so of course if you drop the adverb the sentence no longer makes sense. `somebody` is still the direct object. It might make sense to `stand a drink for someone`, on the other hand, though it would sound odd.

Comment: @Wlerin _Look over_ is obviously a phrasal verb. _Look/stare/gawk/etc. [someone] in the [body part]_ is most definitely not a phrasal verb. It is an idiomatic template that can be used quite productively and just happens to include an indirect object.

Answer (score 5):

No.

There are verbs that take two objects that won’t let you blindly transform this:

- **verb   indirect-object   direct-object**

into  this

- **verb   direct-object   *to/for*   indirect-object**

and be left with legal or meaningful sentences.  Some of these are:

- Pardon me my reach.
- I forgave her the entire incident.
- I envied him his easy smile.
- I begrudged him his easy smile.
- The falling dish pail struck him a good solid knock.
- I excused him the mud on his shoes.
- I forbade him further admittance.
- You cannot permit them full run of the place.
- I denied him his request.

If you look back a few hundred years, you’ll find many more instances of this sort of thing which are now obsolete because they don’t sound right to us anymore.  The Old English dative was not so cut and dry as to always convey a *to/for* relationship.    The dative is the “interested” party here.

Comment: These are exceptions to Dative Alternation. Note that all of them either refer to emotional judgements (_envy, begrudge, excuse_) rather than to transfers, or are extensions of simple transitive verbs (_struck him a knock = knocked him; landed him a blow = struck him,_ etc). There are some 3 place verbs that don't refer to transfer (_elect him president_), and they don't do Dative Alternation, either. But if there's a transfer, they usually do.

Comment: "His wife deemed him a lost cause" doesn't have an indirect object at all.  "Him" is the direct object and "a lost cause" is either an objective complement or a predicate nominative.

Comment: "I'll sport you a twenty" does seem to mean "to" or "for".

Comment: @JohnLawler : Are you really saying that in "elect him president" there's an indirect object?

Comment: . . . ok, maybe you weren't saying that.

Comment: OK, in "His wife deemed him a lost cause", the phrase "a lost cause" is an objective complement.  I think "predicate nominative" comes to mind simply because those phrases would be nominative in Esperanto.

Comment: But "to" is used with "forbid" and "permit": "Nothing was forbidden to him", etc.

Comment: I said they were three place verbs, not that they were indirect objects. And can _to_ really be used with permit? _He permitted the use of the penthouse to her._ I'd star it, though _forbid_ does allow _to_. _Permit_ and _forbid_ **can** take infinitive complements, of course: _She forbids/permits you to go to the dance_. But that _to_ is the infinitive marker, not a dative marker.

Comment: How about "That was permitted to her."?

Comment: So when you say these are exceptions to Dative Alternation, what you mean is that the indirect object is in the third spot rather than the second, yes? Thus, `I forgave her **for** the entire incident`, `I envied him **for** his easy smile`; and `I excused him **for** the mud on his shoes`, etc. A few of the sentences can't be changed like this, but it's nonetheless rather obvious that the first noun is *not* the indirect object  (`struck him`, `forbade him`, etc.). What the second noun is in these cases I do not know.

Comment: For details like these, you probly want to look at [Levin's _English Verb Classes and Alternations_](http://books.google.com/books/about/English_Verb_Classes_and_Alternations.html?id=6wIZWOrcBf8C). There are a number of subclasses.

Comment: I've seen 'She led him a merry dance' analysed as a ditransitive structure, but the conclusion a few of us came to was that it's a poor, look-alike, analysis. One person argued that there was a 'syntactic' rather than 'semantic object' involved. Messy. It's almost certainly an ellipted form: 'She led him [along] in/on a merry dance', with 'a merry dance' an adverbial objective. Cf 'She led him home'.

Comment: In "I envied him his drive and enthusiasm", either object may be deleted. I've seen this described as a rare S-V-DO-DO construction. This hinges, of course, on the related senses available for the verb envy: to envy someone (for something) and to envy something (possessed by someone).

Comment: @Wlerin You're transforming the _direct_ objects here. The phrases are exceptions to dative alternation because the indirect object _cannot_ alternate with a prepositional object.

Comment: @Edwin Why would that have to be S-V-DO-DO? There are several ditransitive verbs that can also be monotransitive; _envy_ just differs in that it has two semantic uses as a monotransitive verb, and the DO can represent either the DO or the IO in the ditransitive use.

Comment: @Janus Applying the deletion test tchrist gives in a comment above. The 3-place construction with 'envy' doesn't match the typical 'transfer' implication of the usual ditransitive construction. The problem of well-defining DOs and IOs is [neither simple nor deemed truly solved](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137038/give-it-me-write-me/137066#137066).

Comment: @Edwin I don't think that test works with _envy_ or _begrudge_ (or similar verbs), simply because their monotransitive uses can have as their DO both the thing envied and the person the thing envied is associated with. Two fundamentally different lexemes, really. It is more coincidence than anything that there happens to be a ditransitive usage where the DO and the IO each corresponds to one of the monotransitive lexemes. I don't see why that would make the ditransitive usage contain two DOs, any more than in “He wrote me a letter”, which is entirely parallel.

Comment: @Janus Not semantically. The fact that the definition of 'ditransitive' is partly semantic is key here: 'In grammar, a ditransitive verb is a verb which takes a subject and two objects which refer to a theme and a recipient' [Wikipedia] In 'He envied John his looks' it seems we have none of the 'transfer' usually associated with the ditransitive structure. I'm not at all saying I agree with the S-V-DO-DO analysis, but I'm saying that I find an S-V-IO-DO analysis dubious too. This whole area needs overhauling; Aarts and others have made a start.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If I can transform a "direct" object into a to/for prepositional phrase, then it wasn't a direct object... The most straightforward analysis of half of these is S-V-DO-IO. (The other half are weird and I have no comment on them.)

Comment: @Wlerin Says who? I’d say S-V-DO-IO is a very _non_-straightforward analysis, since that word order is not usually permitted except dialectally when both objects are enclitic pronouns. It is much simpler to say that there are simply some constructions where indirect objects cannot undergo dative alternation, and consider verbs like _forgive_ as varyingly mono- and ditransitive (which we already know they are anyway), with the monotransitive use also licensing a prepositional complement that happens to use a preposition that also appears in dative alternation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Another “odd” old construct, one allegedly still with some currency northwards of Hadrian’s Wall, is the standard S-V-IO-DO but where DO **is** an enclitic pronoun yet IO is **not**.  Think of the old Jacobite rhyme: *O what’s the rhyme for porringer? / Ken ye the rhyme to porringer? /
The King he had a daughter fair, /
And **gave the Prince of Orange her.***

Comment: @JanuhsBahsJacquet I concede that my superficial analysis was incorrect. I still have some difficulty identifying the first object in most of these examples as an indirect object. It seems in these cases (excluding `struck`) that the first object is interpreted as a non-receiving possessor--it already possesses the direct object and does not receive it from the action of the verb. This appears to fit the Old English use of the dative, but I am not convinced it fits the Modern English criteria for an indirect object.