# send something to someone or somewhere

Tags: word-order, indirect-objects, prepositional-objects

**Background**:

I am writing a computer application which can understand English sentence. For that purpose, I was preparing frames of each word. For example:

> send something to recipient|place

Since *to* can be defined as separate frame;

> to recipient|place

So the frame for *send* can be defined as

> send something

Now I found a phrase;

> "Send him my love"

**Question**

Is there any grammar rule which transforms *Send my love to him* into *Send him my love*, or it is word-specific?

> send recipient something
>
> send something to recipient

Comment: I think that English generally permits the alternative positioning "Send flowers to Algernon" and "Send Algernon flowers." It's just part of the flexibility of the language.

Comment: It's worth noting that only a *recipient* can be an indirect (dative) object; a *place* is a destination and so cannot be treated in the same way: i.e. we can say either *I sent a gift to him* or *I sent him a gift*, but we can only say *I sent a gift to his house*, not **I sent his house a gift*. This has its roots in some Indo-European idea that recipients belong in the dative case and destinations in the accusative; even though English has outgrown its case markings, it hasn't outgrown much of the grammar that accompanied them.

Comment: @Anonym, you gave me a good point. +1

Comment: Examples and non-examples: _bring it to me_ = _bring me it_, _lend it to me_ = _lend me it_, _pass it to me_ = _pass me it_, _give it to me_ = _give me it_, _sing a song to me_ = _sing me a song_, _told it to me_ = _told me it_. But also _do me a favour_ = _do a favour for me_ not _do a favour to me_, _save me a piece_ = _save a piece for me_ not _save a piece to me_ .

Comment: See [this answer on dative transformation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/174454) and its comments. Yes, there is a general rule. However, there are a few dative constructions that cannot be unravelled into prepositional phrases in this way, which is what that other question is asking

Comment: @Sven Yargs +1 for 'flowers' and 'Algernon' in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to know about dative case after receiving some really helpful comments. And I found a very helpful document about [dative shifting](http://www.ucd.ie/pages/97/daultrey.html).

Explanation which exactly meets with my question;

> 3a John sent the parcel to Mary
>
> 3b John sent Mary the parcel
>
> 4a John sent the parcel to the States
>
> 4b * John sent the States the parcel

In both 3 and 4 the direct object, [the parcel], travels towards the indirect object, [Mary] or [the States], making it the Goal of the action. The semantic difference is that in 3 [Mary] is the Beneficiary of the action, the person for whom the parcel is intended, but in 4 [the States] has no such role. For this shift to occur it seems that we must have the right type of verb and the right type of indirect object.

Frames

```
[sender] send (smth) (to [recipient])
[sender] send ([recipient] smth)    ;where recipient is a beneficiary.
```