# Is there an object in this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, objects

> You need to practise your proofreading.

In this sentence, "you" is the subject and "need" is the verb. But is there an object? At the moment I am guessing that there isn't and that *to practise your proofreading* is just a phrase.

I asked someone else and they too did not think there was an object.

Comment: There's a verbal phrase "need to practice".  "proofreading" is the object of the sentence.  Think of "I practice proofreading."  The word "need" is just indicating the modality of necessity.

Comment: This is a complex sentence, with two clauses (and therefore two verbs). Both are transitive; the object of the verb _need_ in the main clause is _(for you) to practice your penmanship_, which is an infinitive complement clause. The object of the verb _practice_ in the complement clause is _your penmanship_. So, yes, there is an object in this sentence; but that's not the way I'd put it.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I just want to congratulate you on 999 answers.

Comment: @JohnLawler, your comment was really helpful. Could you please add it as an answer?

Comment: If you go over 1000 answers, you get leprosy.

Comment: What evidence did your "someone else" give for thinking there wasn't an object?

Comment: @curiousdannii None; however, I asked them whilst they were walking past.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. You need [to practise **your proofreading**].

One test to see if a phrase is an Object in a clause is to see if the phrase concerned can become the Subject of a passivised version of that clause. If it can, even if the result is awkward, then it is definitely an Object. If it can't then it is much less likely to be an Object -- but it still might be.

The noun phrase *your proofreading* will indeed become the Subject of a passivised version of the clause that it occurs in:

- 2. You need [**your proofreading** to be practised]. -- (passivised)

This shows that, in version #1, *your proofreading* is an object of the clause headed by *practised* (which appears in brackets). Of course this means that *your proofreading* (in version #1) has the syntactic function of Object in relation to this clause. It is not however the direct object of the sentence (version #1) as a whole.

---

In the original example,

> 1. You need [**to practise your proofreading**].

the sentence has a Subject, *You*. The predicate consists of the Predicator (read that as meaning "verb"), *need*, and the complement of that verb, which appears in brackets and is: *to practise your proofreading*. This complement is an infinitival clause. Whether you regard this infinitival clause as the object of the verb *need* depends on which grammar you subscribe to. Notice, however, that if we try to passivise the sentence by making this complement the subject, the result is not good. Indeed we may well regard it as ungrammatical:

- 3. *[To practise your proofreading] is needed.

For this reason, as well as many others, many grammarians (such as Postal or Huddleston & Pullum) reject the idea that such infinitival clauses are the direct objects of the verbs in such constructions. The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* describe the syntactic function of such clauses as *catenative complements* ruling out their status as *direct objects*. However, this debate is an ongoing one.

**The Original Poster's question**

The main clause headed by the verb *need* here may or may not have a direct object, depending on which grammar framework you use. However, if it is a direct object, it is an atypical one. The clause embedded in this sentence, headed by the verb *practise* does indeed have a direct object, the noun phrase *your proofreading*.

Comment: er, hmm, er, okay, +1. Though, the framework I'm currently using (H&P CGEL), passivization is not either a sufficient or necessary condition for object-hood. :) . . . There's recently been a crop of interesting questions!

Comment: @F.E. I was aware of the not "necessary" (as indicated, I hope in my answer) but not the not "sufficient". Could you expand?

Comment: "Also, I might have been too general in my previous comment about passivization being a sufficient test for object-hood, for it seems that sufficiency applies only if it is a core-complement NP of an active clause." <== Just copied that a [recent comment of mine](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247509/i-weigh-about-5-lbs#comment536796_247510). -- If the complement is a clause, I think that things are rather unclear, or could be, or something like that. -- You're still up? wow!

Answer (score 2):

What a lot of wrong answers! (Except for John's, of course.) In "You need to practise your proofreading.", the subject of "need" is (as you say) "you", and the object of "need" is "to practice your proofreading".  A test for objects is whether they can be passivized, and here we have "To practice your proofreading is needed".  A test for noun phrases is whether they can be pronominalized, and here, we have "(...Practice your proofreading ...) You need it."

"To practice your proofreading" is a nominalization of the sentence "you practice your proofreading", which means the sentence has been converted into a noun phrase, where it can stand where noun phrases generally stand, for instance as direct object.  That is what is going on in this example, where you practicing your proofreading is said to be what you need.

Comment: The OP asked "is there an object" in this sentence. If you accept a grammar where "to practise your proofreading" is an object, then there's two objects in this sentence - unless you'd like to argue that "your proofreading" isn't an object of the verb *practise*?

Comment: Well, @Araucaria, there are two sentences involved in the construction, but it seems clear that in the question, "this sentence" refers to the sentence whose subject is "you" and whose verb is "need".

Comment: In any case, as you'd appreciate, not every grammar's going to accept "to practise your proofreading" as an object - and no native speaker's going to accept "To practise your proofreading is needed" as a felicitous or grammatical sentence!!!

Comment: No, there's one sentence and two clauses - it seems to me. In addition, if the infinitival clause "To practise your proofreading" was the bona fide grammatical subject of a sentence, the subject of the clause would not be "you" any more than the subject of "To err is human" is "you". Sorry if I seem a little pugnacious, but so's your opening sentence.

Comment: @Araucaria, I'm trying to decipher your comment.  You mean "was the bona fide grammatical object ..." ??  Are you quarreling with my implication that the understood subject of "practice" is "you"?

Comment: Not in the original sentence, but in the "passivised" one - yes!

Comment: *"To practice your proofreading is needed"* <== That sounds a bit off to my ear, imo. Maybe I'll need a specific context, er, . . . okay, I'll butt out now. :)

Comment: If "To practice your proofreading is needed" is ungrammatical, then either some constraint I have not taken account of has been broken (perhaps moving the subject of "need" across the like subjects of "practice" and "proofread") or else maybe "need" simply doesn't have a direct object, here.  I'm not against those conclusions, really.  I'm more concerned to point out the relationship of the OP's question to the grammaticality of certain other constructions.

Answer (score 0):

Proofreading is the object. The possessive pronoun "your" may be the reason why you think there is no object. Assuming the sentence is made without "your"-You need to practise proofreading. It becomes more obvious that proofreading is the object.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

Subject/Verb:

> You need

Infinitive:

> To pratise

Object of the infinitive:

> Your proofreading

`Your proofreading` is the object of the infinitive phrase `to practise`. However, the entire phrase `to practise your proofreading` is the object of the verb `need`.

**Quick answer:**

There are two objects. One is the object of the infinitive. One is a phrase, which is the object of the verb.